# Why is my PostgreSQL ORDER BY case-insensitive?

Tags: postgresql, collation

I have Postgres 9.4.4 running on Debian and I get the following `ORDER BY` behavior:

```
veure_test=# show LC_COLLATE;
 lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8
(1 row)

veure_test=# SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b CD Capacitor', ' ') ORDER BY 1;
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 a
 A
 b
 c
 Capacitor
 CD
 d
 D
(8 rows)
```

And `uname -a`:

```
Linux ---- 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However, on my iMac, with Postgres 9.3.4, I get the following:

```
veure_test=# show LC_COLLATE;
 lc_collate  
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8
(1 row)

veure_test=# SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b CD Capacitor', ' ') ORDER BY 1;
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 A
 CD
 Capacitor
 D
 a
 b
 c
 d
(8 rows)
```

And the `uname -a`:

```
Darwin ---- 14.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I'm mystified by why the Debian version appears to be case-insensitive and the OS X version is not. What am I missing, or what other information do I need to provide?

**Update**: On my Mac, the `pg_collation` table shows I have an `en_US.UTF-8` collation, but on Debian, I have an `en_US.utf8` collation. Thus, on my Mac:

```
veure_test=# with foo as (
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b CD Capacitor', ' ') as bar
   )
SELECT bar FROM foo
ORDER BY bar collate "en_US.UTF-8";                                                                                                                                                                                      
    bar    
-----------
 A
 CD
 Capacitor
 D
 a
 b
 c
 d
(8 rows)
```

And on Debian:

```
veure_test=# with foo as (
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b CD Capacitor', ' ') as bar
   )
SELECT bar FROM foo
ORDER BY bar collate "en_US.utf8";
    bar    
-----------
 a
 A
 b
 c
 Capacitor
 CD
 d
 D
(8 rows)
```

So `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_US.utf8` have different sort orders?

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test on, so I'm shooting in the dark here... Any chance that the string `'D d a A c b CD Capacitor'` is not being cast as a `text` field on the Mac?  I.E., try `SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b CD Capacitor'::text, ' ') ORDER BY 1;` and see what happens...

Comment: Same result. In other news, turns out that `select * from pg_collation` shows the Debian box has `en_US.utf8`, while the OS X has `en_US.UTF-8`.  Using those to explicitly force collation on the respective boxes shows different sort orders :(

Comment: And I've posted an update which might explain the problem, but for me, it merely deepens the mystery.

And I've now found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967555/postgres-collation-differences-osx-v-ubuntu and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395317/why-does-utf-8-text-sort-in-different-order-between-os-x-and-linux

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres uses the collation implementation from the OS which makes this kind of behaviour OS dependent (which I personally consider a bug - a DBMS should behave identical regardless of the OS). So this boils down to differences in the system libraries between Debian and OSX

Comment: There will be disagreement between Postgres and other parts of the system if the sort order does not fall in line with the rest. I, too, prefer identical behavior, but I wouldn't call it a bug to follow the system locale. Ultimately, identical locales should behave identically across OS. The [Debian locale seems to right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order), Apple seems to be at fault (unless there is some other explanation).

Comment: One problem Postgresql faces is finding a working UTF8 collation system that's compatible with the BSD license.  on linux they can use the collations from glibc.  but that's LGPL so they can't distribute it under a BSD license.

Answer (score 32):

> So `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_US.utf8` have different sort orders?

No, these both are the same, just a different naming convention.

> I'm mystified by why the Debian version appears to be case-insensitive and the OS X version is not.

Yes, you are correct. This is the default behavior on Mac. Collations don't work on any BSD-ish OS (incl. OSX) for `UTF8` encoding.

Here is a reference to prove that:

[Problems with sort order (UTF8 locales don't work](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/216)

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) said, Postgres uses the collation implementation from the OS. There is no way to get the same result on both operating systems.

In your case you may(I said maybe)do like this: `ORDER BY lower(fieldname)`.

Comment: Take care to verify performance when using `ORDER BY function()` on potentially large resultsets - as it stops an index being used for the sort it will almost certainly cause an extra sort operation (possibly on disc) and it may change the query planner's method of attacking your query more widely.

Comment: @David Spillett: You are right about the Order function. I think my answer is more focused on why the OP is having different sorting fashion in iMac and Debian. Thanks

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfectly fine and covers the question completely. Mentioning "testing with real data after changes that might affect query plan" has become a habitual reaction in me though (much like mentioning testing in any discussion of backups, and such forth) as it is easy to forget (and people often do) or not even know to in the case of people newer to database work.

Comment: @DavidSpillett I doesn't stop an index from being used,  it only stops a plain index from being used. An index on the function result will be used if present.  `create index l_bar on foo ( lower(bar)) ;`

Comment: "There is no way to get the same result on both operating systems." 
That's only partly correct or at least for me this statement was kind of misleading. If you set LC_COLLATE to 'C' (Ascii) the output should be the same.