# Case-insensitive order while preserving the case of the returned strings

Tags: postgresql

I have noticed that when ordering, PostgreSQL (I'm currently working with 11 but I think the same applies to 10 and 9) is case sensitive. It returns upper-cased string before lower-cased one.
For instance, let's say I have the `friends` table with 3 records and the `first_name` column contains respectively  `adam`, `Tony`, `Paul`.

```
SELECT name
FROM friends
ORDER BY name
```

returns

```
[name]
 Paul
 Tony
 adam
```

To get them alphabetically ordered regardless of the case, I can use the `lower` function.

```
SELECT name
FROM friends
ORDER BY lower(name)
```

returns

```
[name]
 adam
 Paul
 Tony
```

Now I need to join the `friends` table with the `cities` table in order to get only the friends associated with a city while keeping the friends alphabetically ordered **and without changing the case of their name** .

The following query is valid

```
SELECT DISTINCT lower(friends.name)
FROM friends
INNER JOIN cities
ON friends.city_id = cities.id
ORDER BY lower(friends.name)
```

But the returned names are all lowercase.
However, the query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT friends.name
FROM friends
INNER JOIN cities
ON friends.city_id = cities.id
ORDER BY lower(friends.name)
```

returns the error

> ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list.

What is the simplest way to apply a case-insensitive order while preserving the case of the returned strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't use a join. This also removes the need for a DISTINCT.

```
select f.name
from friends f
where exists (select *
              from cities c
              where f.city_id = c.id)
order by lower(f.name);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SNA62411

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a COLLATE clause after ORDER BY however it seems there is no clear collation modifier for beeing case sensitive or not — it depends on the OS and encoding.

I guess you can sort by lower/upper(col), but you might need to watch out for performance problems if you don’t have a function index on that expression. (You would need to add `upper(friends.name), friends.name` to your select list and ignore the sort column)

There are quite some topics dealing with that on SE, for example: [Why is my PostgreSQL ORDER BY case-insensitive?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106964/why-is-my-postgresql-order-by-case-insensitive)

Comment: Currently Postgres does not support case insensitive collations.